# 'Select' 2 pieces of info (XSLT file)

Tags: magento, xslt, sage-erp

I am trying to link our Magento website with Sage 50 with a piece of software.

We would like the customers first name and last name to go into the company field.

Below are the 3 lines I assume I have to tweak:

```
   <Forename><xsl:value-of select="billing_address/firstname"/></Forename>
    <Surname><xsl:value-of select="billing_address/lastname"/></Surname>
    <Company><xsl:value-of select="billing_address/company"/></Company>
```

How do I combine first name and last name in 1 line? looking for something like:

```
    <Company><xsl:value-of select="billing_address/firstname, billing_address/lastname"/></Company>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, whitespace-only text nodes are ignored by the XSLT engine, so what you tried above can be rewritten like the following:

```
<Company>
   <xsl:value-of select="billing_address/firstname, billing_address/lastname"/>
</Company>
```

Second, you have to understand that `xsl:value-of` generates a text node.  The following will generate 2 text nodes, with resp. the first and last names:

```
<Company>
   <xsl:value-of select="billing_address/firstname"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="billing_address/lastname"/>
</Company>
```

Then if I understand correctly, you want to seperate both with the string `", "`.  You can use `xsl:text` to generate a fixed-content text node:

```
<Company>
   <xsl:value-of select="billing_address/firstname"/>
   <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="billing_address/lastname"/>
</Company>
```

In the above, you can put the `", "` directly between both value-of, but then you can't control the indentation.  Usuaully, when I generate fixed text, I always use `xsl:text`.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to tell us which version of XSLT you are using. Your proposed code

```
<xsl:value-of select="billing_address/firstname, billing_address/lastname"/>
```

is fine in 2.0, and you can get the comma by adding the attribute `separator=", "/>`. But this won't work in 1.0, where `xsl:value-of` will only output the first item if you give it a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can give

```
    <Company><xsl:value-of select="concat(billing_address/firstname,', ', billing_address/lastname)"/></Company>
```

a try...